# Android spinner text size

Tags: android, view, android-layout, android-widget, spinner

Due to some designing issues i am designing my spinner with smaller width and height. And this smaller width and height not showing complete text written in the prompt of spinner.
Please help if any solution possible to decrease the text size of the spinner.

I am attaching the screen shot of the problem.

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/97147

Answer (score 6):

Use the below code as per your need...

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Questions, R.layout.custom_spinner_list);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.customer_spinner);
            spin.setAdapter(adapter);
```

custom_spinner_list.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:text="@+id/TextView01"
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textColor="#000000">
</TextView>
```

customer_spinner.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:text="@+id/TextView01"
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:height="42dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding = "2dp">
</TextView>
```

Comment: Thanks Vineet, This will decrease text size when we open spinner but i want on the unopened spinner reduced text size so that it can display the content in the box as i attached screen shot.

Comment: make sure in xml where you defined the spinner there is android:layout_height="wrap_content" and it worked for me in unopened condition too.......plz check...

Answer (score 0):

Try using **android:paddingTop = "2dp" or android:paddingTop = "1dp"** etc, which ever is suitable.